# Track route on google map Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to develop an Android application with track my route on google map.is it possible?if yes please can you tell me what is the API and any sample code link?

Answer (score -1):

Follow this link   [Google Maps Android: How can i draw a route line to see directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425740/google-maps-android-how-can-i-draw-a-route-line-to-see-directions/19426499#19426499) & save all the latitude longitude valu for tracking the location .

Use api for getting direction

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
```

or

If you only want to track the location  use

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (lastLocationloc == null) { 
               lastLocationloc = location;
           }
        //public void setPoints (List<LatLng> points)
         LatLng LatLng_origin = new LatLng( 13.133333, 78.133333); //kolar
         LatLng LatLng3 = new LatLng(21.4949767, 86.942657999);   // bbsr
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);


    }
```

Any more doubt ??